# await sets HttpContext.Current to null/prior - cannot set it manually

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await

How do I make the await resume with the manually set `HttpContext.Current` / `CallContext.HostContext`? All awaits changes it (does not restore it / restores it to other value) when it returns to it original state.

Where does it restore it from and how to override that?

I set it manually to virtually execute pages, if done from application/scheduler where context is null, it returns to null (if from another page, it returns to that).

```
var wr = new System.Web.Hosting.SimpleWorkerRequest(...);
var context = new HttpContext(wr);
HttpContext.Current = context;
...
await Task.Delay(100);
// HttpContext.Current has now returned to old value / null
```

I have tried various things like setting `SynchronizationContext` when it is null - even forced the context to create the internal AspNetSynchronizationContext using reflection - but nothing helps.

(the answer is not not to user `HttpContext.Current` and not to use null sync context with `.Wait()` etc.)

Comment: May I ask why the need for changing the context?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Because there are no context at that time (or need to swtich to a new for the new page) + webform controls are using it

Answer (score 0):

> ... SynchronizationContext ...

That should have helped and is the way to go. In fact the only way that I can think of. It is the only hook into `await` that allows you to control the environment of the continuation. Without seeing the code the mistake can't be found.

If you can't get the built-in sync context to cooperate you need to install your own one that sufficiently behaves like the built-in one.

`HttpContext.Current` is stored in some "call context" which is a .NET concept. Decompile the code to see where exactly it is stored, I forgot.

You should probably use a different approach entirely. Call an internal URL to execute your page and all these issues go away. No need to do hacks anymore. If this is a high-frequency operation consider running multiple pages per fake HTTP request. That reduces the overhead.

Comment: yes - thanks, but been there and got nothing. Cannot just execute using a url (and also the executer needs a context) and using a handler it ends up with the same problem.

Comment: Well, I can't (and nobody else can) help you without seeing the code. You made a mistake there. The general approach works. Help us help you and post code.

Comment: "sufficiently behaves" is especially tricky on ASP.NET. There are a number of helper methods that just downcast straight to `AspNetSynchronizationContext` and silently fail if you're using your own. :/